# How to keep precision on int64_t = int64_t * float?

Tags: c, integer-division, single-precision

I would like to perform a correction on an `int64_t` by a factor in the range `[0.01..1.2]` with precision is about `0.01`. The naive implementation would be:

```
int64_t apply_correction(int64_t y, float32_t factor)
{
    return y * factor;
}
```

Unfortunately, I will loose precision either if I cast `factor` to `int32` or if I cast `y` into `float`.

However, if I can ensure `y` has its maximum value below `1<<56`, I can use this trick:

```
(1<<8) * (y / (int32_t)(factor * (1<<8)))
```

How can I solve this problem if my input value can be bigger than `1<<56`?

**Plot twist:**

I am running on a 32-bit architecture where `int64_t` is an emulated type and where I don't have any support for double precision. The architecture is SHARC from Analog Devices.

Comment: What's wrong with `y * (int_64t)factor;` ?

Comment: @luk32 it will not work as `factor` is in the range 0.01-1.2.

Comment: if you don't have support for double precision you can write a library for that, or just use tons of double/multiple precision libraries out there. But using double still doesn't help you because it has only 53 bits of precision, so you can't get full 64-bit precision

Comment: @fluter Oh, I misread `int64` for `float64` and completetly didn't understand what what the problem was. I even absent-mindedly retyped `int` thinking abotu float. I guess it was to early for even basic brain activity for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you calculate `((int64_t)1 << 57) * 100` or `* 256`, you will have a signed integer overflow, which would lead to your code having undefined behaviour. If instead you used `uint64_t` and the value, then your code would be well-defined but definedly ill-behaved.

---

However it is possible to make this work for numbers almost up to `(1 << 63 / 1.2)`.

If `y` were an `uint64_t` you can split the original number to most-significant 32 bits shifted right by 32, and the least-significant 32 bits, multiply this by `(int32_t)(factor * (1 << 8))`.

Then you do not right-shift the most-significant bits by 8 after the multiplication, but left-shift by 24; then add together:

```
uint64_t apply_uint64_correction(uint64_t y, float32_t factor)
{
    uint64_t most_significant = (y >> 32) * (uint32_t)(factor * (1 << 8));
    uint64_t least_significant = (y & 0xFFFFFFFFULL) * (uint32_t)(factor * (1 << 8));     
    return (most_significant << 24) + (least_significant >> 8);
}
```

Now, `apply_uint64_correction(1000000000000, 1.2)` would result in `1199218750000`, and `apply_uint64_correction(1000000000000, 1.25)` would result in `1250000000000`.

---

Actually you can make more precision out of it if you can guarantee the range of `factor`:

```
uint64_t apply_uint64_correction(uint64_t y, float32_t factor)
{
    uint64_t most_significant = (y >> 32) * (uint32_t)(factor * (1 << 24));
    uint64_t least_significant = (y & 0xFFFFFFFFULL) * (uint32_t)(factor * (1 << 24));     
    return (most_significant << 8) + (least_significant >> 24);
}
```

`apply_uint64_correction(1000000000000, 1.2)` would give `1200000047683` on my computer; this is also the maximum precision you can get out of it, if `float32_t` has 24-bit mantissa.

---

The above algorithm would work for signed positive numbers as well, but as signed shifts for negative numbers are a grey area I'd take note of the sign, then convert the value to `uint64_t`, do the calculations portably, and then negate if original sign was negative.

```
int64_t apply_correction(int64_t y, float32_t factor) {
    int negative_result = 0;
    uint64_t positive_y = y;
    if (y < 0) {
        negative_result = 1;
        positive_y = -y;
    }

    uint64_t result = apply_uint64_correction(positive_y, factor);
    return negative_result ? -(int64_t)result : result;
}
```

Comment: What happens to the remainder/fraction from the most-significant part?

Comment: @WeatherVane oops a shortcut :D

Comment: @WeatherVane fixed

Answer (score 3):

How about doing it in integer space?

```
/* factor precision is two decimal places */
int64_t apply_correction(int64_t y, float32_t factor)
{
    return y * (int32_t)(factor * 100) / 100;
}
```

This does assume `y` is not very close to the maximum value, but it gets you a little closer than 56 bits.

Comment: This `int32_t(factor * 100)` won't compile in  C.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Integer overflow is possible with any solution here, since an int64_t is multiplied by up to 1.2 then returned as the same type.  I've updated my answer to mention the specific caveats.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: "*factor in the range [0.01..1.2]  ...  y has its maximum value below 1<<56*" which overlfow?

Comment: @alk "How can I solve this problem if my input value can be bigger than 1<<56?"

Comment: Aarg ... I parsed this 1<<56 completely wrong! :} @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @JohnZwinck this gets you about 1 bit **closer** to maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use float numbers.

```
int64_t apply_correction(int64_t y, float32_t factor)
{
  int64_t factor_i64 = factor * 100f;

  return (y * factor_i64) / 100ll;
}
```

This is assuming that `y * factor_i64 * 100` will not overflow.

Comment: Doesn't this assume `long long` is available on the system?

Comment: @Qix Yes, indeed it is assuming that standard C is used. You could also write `(int64_t)0`. At any rate it doesn't really matter because of implicit type promotion through balancing. That is, `(y * factor) / 100;` is equivalent and safe. I just like to be explicit with types.

Comment: @cmaster Oops indeed, fixed.

Comment: standard **C99** C, sure. `long long` wasn't available in c89/c90/c95, which should be taken into consideration given that this is an embedded system.

Comment: @Qix If you are maintaining old stuff, sure. But if your project is a new one, there are no excuses for using C90 still. Note that the types `int64_t` and `float32_t` were introduced in C99. Also per SO C tag policy: unless the OP specifically states that they are interested in an older version of the language, always assume they are using the current version of the standard, which is C11.

Comment: Fair enough. It's always a concern, though, since a few embedded systems' compilers are still pinned to C89 due to the company going out of business, etc.